# NVSRAM - Storage Capacitor Selection

Tags: non-volatile-memory

I was reading this document from cypress website on Various storage capacitor options for nvSRAM. In page 2 , under the heading 'key characteristics' (see link below), I came across various values for capacitors for different densities of nvSRAM.(e.g. 4 Mbit parallel nvSRAM-  68 μF with 10% tolerance)

My question is this: What basis did they use to arrive on particular value of a capacitor?

[Capacitor options- nvSRAM](http://www.cypress.com/?docID=42227)

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to have been included in the question.

Comment: @PeterJ I've added it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datasheet says that the capacitor needs to provide enough energy for the "store to nvram" action to work. Cypress will have done simulations of the chip to work out how much current is consumed for how long during this phase. That gives a value in coulombs for the charge consumed in that time. Plus their knowledge of what the minimum voltage must be during this process, gives a value for the capacitor.

Comment: Nailed it.  Cypress would have also verified the results in environmental test as part of qualification too.